# How do I add a where clause for a databound combobox?

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

Let's say I have the books table in my database, composed of the following:

- IdBook (int)
- Author (string)
- Status (boolean)

And I have the C# combobox bookComboBox in Form1, which is databound to the Books table.

How can I make it so that the combobox only includes items where status = true?

Comment: How are you binding the data to the combo box?

Comment: Show your current code. Also note that there is no such term as "C# combobox", and there are many combobox controls in different .net framework areas, so you need to clarify which one do you have in mind.

Comment: If you don't want to add it to the query, don't bind directly but put a BindingSource between comboBox and dataSource. Then add a Filter to the BindingSource and Refresh it!

Comment: ...or modify query with WHERE clause.

Comment: @TaW This doesn't work if the underlying data source does not support filtering, since `BindingSource` is just delegating filter/sort stuff. The only standard source that supports filtering is `DataView`, and it does not need `BindingSource` to do that.

Comment: @TaW Ahhh, thanks! This worked!

Comment: @Ivan, thanks for the info; so using the DataView would also do; using a Table sounds like there is a Dataview indeed..

Comment: @TaW Yep, and looks like OP is luckily (for him) using the old good `DataTable` (or `DataSet`)  already :-) Problem solved.